# Missing data while reading incremental rows of data from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database

I am building an application that needs to read new rows from a MySQL table  that is being consistently and concurrently inserted into. I'm unable to design an logic which can ensure I process every row inserted into my MySQL table.

Here is my current solution.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  col1 varchar(20),
  col2 varchar(20),
  dateadded timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

This table is only ever inserted into (no updates, no deletes) by a number of concurrent connections.

In my application, I maintain state of last processed "id" i.e. "lastProcessedId".

Step 1: Get new rows from the table

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, dateadded
FROM my_table
WHERE id > {lastProcessedId}
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Step 2: Process the result set

In my application, I loop through the results, do some processing for each row, and update my internal {lastProcessedId} to be the last "id" I saw in the results

Go back to Step 1.

Here is the problem.

The rows that are visible with the query in Step 1 may have out of order ids, and hence there is a possibility that I will miss processing some rows in the application because it looks like in MySQL the AUTO_INCREMENT id is incremented at the beginning of the transaction and not on COMMIT.

Scenario.

```
1. Let say the table has 5 rows with the MAX(id) also being 5.
2. Transaction 1 to insert a new row to my_table starts, it will get an internal id of 6.
3. Transaction 2 to insert a new row to my_table starts, it will get an internal id of 7.
4. Transaction 2 commits.
5. My application which reads the "new" data runs the query on Step 1 (previous lastProcessedId is 5).
6. My result set will include row with id 7. My application updates lastProcessedId to 7.
7. Transaction 1 commits with id of 6.
8. With the next iteration of my application, I would have missed processing row with id 6.
```

Is there a way to incrementally process rows from a MySQL table, with a guarantee that ever row gets processed by my application. I can change both the table schema and the application logic, but haven't figured out anything that solves the problem. I found similar issues with using the "dateadded" column.

Any thoughts, or is such a solution not possible?

Comment: How about a processed column, and a script that simply processes all unprocessed rows?

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the comment. Having a processed column is not feasible, as this would entail, I would have to update all the rows in the my_table table. Running such an update would require I have a list of ids processed and with each run can have tens of thousands of rows processed, and running such an update query on a list of ids will not be performant.